# Git merge: keep only the staged commits and toss the rest?

Tags: git

While doing a merge/rebase, I often hit this scenario:
 - hit some conflicts
 - resolve the important ones, moving them to the index

Then, there's a bunch of unstaged junk and I just want to keep HEAD version. Ideally I could just do "git commit && git reset --hard", but git wont let me commit while there's still unmerged stuff pending. I tried "git stash save --keep-index" but that fails. I tried "git diff | patch -Rp1" (and various mutations). I dont think any of the "git reset" modes match what I want.

There's gotta be a way to just say "I got what I want, just discard the rest".

Answer (score 2):

There is no out of the box solution, but you could create an alias.

You can use:

```
git checkout HEAD -- <list of files to keep as HEAD>
```

to specify that you want to keep the given files as they were in `HEAD`.

To get a list of remaining conflicts you can use:

```
git diff --name-only --diff-filter=U
```

Then putting it together as an alias gives:

```
alias gitkeeprest="for file in $(git diff --name-only --diff-filter=U); do git checkout HEAD -- $file; done"
```

With that in place you would:

- Start the merge as usual.
- Resolve the parts that you are interested in adding them to the index.
- Put the rest back to as the `HEAD` version by running `gitkeeprest`.

Comment: This doesnt quite work. This removes all changes made in the file. I'm hoping to find a solution where I can stage changes in that file and discard all the rest.

Comment: @JaredGrubb I was suggesting the `git checkout HEAD -- ....` be run on the files you want to remove the changes from, as in the "unstaged junk ... to keep HEAD version". I've edited the answer to try and make it clearer.